# Is there any efficient way to loop through set and save the value if there are multiple/one matches?

Tags: java, loops, set

I have Set of VehicleType, I am looking for efficient way to loop through set and check for all the values, if there is one or multiple matches I would like to save them all in array or list? Is there any efficient/better way to achieve this?

Here is my code

```
private void invokeProcessorDispatcher(Set<VehicleType> vehicleTypes)
    {
        while(vehicleTypes != null){
            Set<VehicleType> results = new HashSet<>();

                for ( VehicleType vehicleName : vehicleTypes)
                {
                    if (vehicleName.equals("US")){
                        LOGGER.info(zMETHOD + "Vehicles provideds: " + vehicleName);

                    }else if (vehicleName.equals("VIP")){
                        LOGGER.info(zMETHOD + "Vehicles provided: " + vehicleName);

                    }else if (vehicleName.equals("Ins")){
                        LOGGER.info(zMETHOD + "Vehicles provided: " + vehicleName);

                    }else{
                        LOGGER.warn(String.format("Unknown vehicle type provided: [%s]",
                                        vehicleName));
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: A set can't have duplicates; if you want to know all of the values two sets share, you could get their intersection.

Comment: Note that `vehicleName.equals("US")` will (/should) never be true.

Comment: @AndyTurner I did not get your point

Comment: I think what Andy is trying to say is that your code should probably be something like `vechicleType.getVehicleName().equals("US");` In your current code, you are comparing `VechicleType` to a `String`.

Comment: Also `while(vehicleTypes != null){` seem like an infinite loop.

Comment: @Sedrick there is this line of code from where this method is being called          -- Set<VehicleType> vehicleTypes = getVehicleTypes(vehicleTypesParamValue);

Comment: Unless `VechicleType` extends `String`, your comment is irrelevant. Since `Sting` is `final`, I doubt that's the case. Take some time to get a better understanding of Java's basic programming ideas before moving forward.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly your HashSet is of type VehicleType and vehicleName.equals(" ") will work only if you override equals method in VehicleType class which is not advisable.

And Secondly, if VehicleType contains only vehicleName then you can directly use hashSet of type String.

eg:

```
HashSet<String> vehicleTypes = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: I think, in this case, it is bad advice to suggest overriding an objects equal method to compare it to a String.

Comment: @Sedrick I did not suggest. I said it only works if equal method is overridden. Infact I suggested to use String in HashSet generic.

Comment: Very true, but if I was a novice and saw that part of your comment, I would think one course of action would be to override the equals method.

Comment: Okay. Its all a perception. I will update my answer based on your feedback.